# ReactJS - UseRef, instead of useState, to replace props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, image, react-hooks

I have the following ImageFallback component. It provides a fallback, `svg` image, when they original one is not present.

```
export interface ImageProps {
  srcImage: string;
  classNames?: string;
  fallbackImage?: FallbackImages;
}

const Image = ({
  srcImage,
  classNames,
  fallbackImage = FallbackImages.GENERAL_FALLBACK
}: ImageProps) => {
  const imgToSourceFrom = `srcImage`;
  const imgToFallbackTo = `fallbackImage`;

  const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState<string>(imgToSourceFrom);

  return <img src={imgUrl} className={classNames} onError={() => setImgUrl(imgToFallbackTo)} />;
};

export default Image;
```

Now I want to do the same using `useRef` instead of `useState`. I am kind of confused since, I am not using refs vey often. **So, any idea, how can I make use of `useRef` when `onError` has been called, in order to change the source of the image??**

I tried this, but no luck:

```
  const imageRef = useRef(imgToFallbackTo);

  console.log(imageRef.current); // this print the fallback..
  return <img src={imgToSourceFrom} className={classNames} onError={() => imageRef.current} />;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Is your current approach not working for you?

Comment: Well, It is working just fine, but it was suggested to me, that using state, to update a single prop, is kind of an overkill.. And I should use refs instead.. So, I guess, I would like to try it out.

Comment: If you want to try using refs here for practice and as a learning exercise, I suggest you start by reading this: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html -- that page should give you the tools necessary to solve this. 
If it's about performance/optimization, then don't worry about it. Using state here is just fine, until it actually causes you problems.

Comment: Thank you!! Will take a look. Was reading just the hook, but I guess reading the refs as a whole is a good start..

Answer (score 1):

So, not sure, If what I end up with is better or worse, but it works, and my tests are passing.

```
export interface ImageProps {
  srcImage: string;
  classNames?: string;
  fallbackImage?: FallbackImages;
}

const Image = ({
  srcImage,
  classNames,
  fallbackImage = FallbackImages.FALLBACK
}: ImageProps) => {
  const imgToSourceFrom = srcImage;
  const imgToFallbackTo = fallbackImage;

  const imageRef = useRef(null);
  const whenImageIsMissing = () => {
    imageRef.current.src = imgToFallbackTo;
  };

  return (
    <img ref={imageRef} src={imgToSourceFrom} className={classNames} onError={whenImageIsMissing} />
  );
};

export default Image;
```

If you know of a better solution, please don't hesitate to post.